# Group structure associated to the equation $y^2 = x^2 + x + 1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, number-theory, commutative-algebra, polynomials

The elliptic curve group law allows us to add two solutions $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2)$ of the equation $y^2 = x^3 + ax + b$ to obtain a new solution $(x_3, y_3)$. Is there an analogous group law associated to the equation $y^2 = x^2 + x + 1$?

Comment: It's not a research level question. The standard solution - find one point, then consider the intersection with a line with a rational slope through that point. The second point of intersection will also have rational coordinates.

Comment: See, for example, Franz Lemmermeyer's *Conics - a Poor Man's Elliptic Curves*: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0311306

Comment: Thanks so much for this reference - it's exactly what I needed!

Comment: [Note your title equation has both $x,y$ to second power, but in body it's $y^3.$]

Comment: If there is a group law, it does not need to be equal to a chords and tangents as it is for elliptic curves. It could be. My opinion is that NOT. If it were possible with this zero genus curve, then this would have already been established by mathematicians.

Answer (score 2):

If $char(k)\ne 2$ then

- $y^2=x^2+x+1$ is isomorphic through $x=z-1/2$ to $y^2=z^2+3/4$
- Which is isomorphic through $y = \frac{u+v}{2},z=\frac{u-v}{2}$ to $uv=3/4$.
- If $char(k)\ne 3$ then it is isomorphic to $uw=1$ through $v=\frac43w$
- Which is the multiplicative group $GL_1(k)$ whose group law is $(u_1,w_1).(u_2,w_2)=(u_1u_2,w_1w_2)$

If $char(k)=2$ then through $y=t-x$ the curve is isomorphic to $\Bbb{A}^1_k$ which is a group. If $char(k)=3$ then the curve is isomorphic to $y^2=z^2$ which is not irreducible, removing $(0,0)$ (the only singular point) it becomes $GL_1(k)\cup GL_1(k)= GL_1(k) \times \pm 1$ which does have a group law.

Comment: Why do you need to remove a point in char. 2? The affine line has a group law of its own, doesn't it? It just becomes the additive group instead of the multiplicative group.

Comment: Yes tks, now in every case the non-singular points form a group. No idea if we could see it in the $\Bbb{Z}$-scheme $Spec(\Bbb{Z}[x,y]/(y^2-x^2-x-1))$